# WSL 2 Access DVD-ROM

Tags: dvd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been playing around with Windows Subsystem for Linux v2 (WSL 2).

I have Ubuntu with WSL 2 correctly configured.

I have a large collection of DVDs that I am in the middle of backing up to my hard drive, but no Windows tools are as good as Brasero...

Long story short, I installed Brasero in my Ubuntu WSL but I cannot figure out where or how to access my computer's DVD-ROM from the ubuntu CLI.

I know this was not possible with WSL v1, but in WSL 2 this should be possible, right? since it is a full-fletched linux system with full kernel capabilities and whatnot.

TL;DR

How to mount/share/use Windows DVD-ROM from Ubuntu WSL2?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Regarding creation of iso files, see mkisofs discussed here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90793/create-iso-image-from-folder-via-terminal-commands

Answer (score 9):

That should be

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/d
$ sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d
```

and you should see the file at `/mnt/d/`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I didn't understand the commands, so I googled and found this: https://www.howtogeek.com/331053/how-to-mount-removable-drives-and-network-locations-in-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

Comment: I then tried to run `dd if=/mnt/d of=here.iso` but I got the message: *dd: /mnt/d: Is a directory*, perhaps `mount` this is not what I want?